# Winston Colorizer throwing error

Tags: winston

Updated winston to 3.0.0 
Got this error when running my nodejs application
the following error appears

```
  TypeError: colors[Colorizer.allColors[lookup]] is not a function
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are adding custom colors to your Winston configuration you can only use colors defined by the [colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) package. 
This was the issue I had.

Comment: i changed the winston configuration and that solved my error

         "format: winston.format.combine(
              winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
              winston.format.simple()
         )"

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `format.colorize`, you must take care to always indicate the log level.

You can indicate it as the initial parameter, in this case 'error':

```
logger.log('error', 'hello', { message: 'world' });
```

You can call its specific method:

```
logger.error('hello', { message: 'world' });
```

The problem that you encountered occurs if at any time you omit the level; for example, if you write something like this:

```
logger.log('hello', { message: 'world' });
```

Answer (score 2):

*Used winstone package: version 3.8.0*

**If you are using colorize() from Winstone package, and you created a custom level, you must define a color for this level.**

Winston is using logform package for supplying default colors.
The crash will occur in colorize.js file inside logform package:

colorize.js:

```
    if (!Array.isArray(Colorizer.allColors[lookup])) {
      return colors[Colorizer.allColors[lookup]](message);
    }
```

**'lookup' variable will be undefined if you won't define a color for your custom level.**

Notice how I define a color for 'request' level

```
import { config, addColors } from 'winston';


// Adding a custom level named 'request'
const levels = { ...config.syslog.levels, request: 6.5 };

// Configuring 'request' color
addColors({ ...config.syslog.colors, request: config.syslog.colors.debug });
```

[image]

(Notice there is a "request" color - it got added)